# How to handle Asterisk SendText cmd in Ozeki

Tags: asterisk, ozeki

We're trying to get custom data sent back from `Asterisk` to our `Ozeki softphone` (a TaskId).

So far I've found that `Asterisk` can send text messages via `SIP` using the [asterisk-cmd-sendtext](https://www.voip-info.org/asterisk-cmd-sendtext). I've debugged in `Asterisk` and have confirmed that the command is being executed.

In `Ozeki`, I first tried using the `InstantMessaging.MessageReceived` event listener, but it never got triggered.

Then I tried implementing `SetSIPMessageManipulator(ISIPMessageManipulator manipulator)` ([documentation](http://www.voip-sip-sdk.com/p_89-how-to-work-with-sip-and-sdp-in-voip-sip-calls-voip.html)). That too, however, was never called.

**How do I consume the message sent from Asterisk?**

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the `SetSIPMessageManipulator(ISIPMessageManipulator manipulator)` should be added **after** the phone is registered, but **before** the event listeners (like the statechanged event) is wired up.